# Handle null values coming in request in Spring request handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In Spring 3:
My Bean:

```
public class UserFormBean {

    private String userEmail;
    private String userMobNo;

    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }
    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }
    public String getUserMobNo() {
        return userMobNo;
    }
    public void setUserMobNo(String userMobNo) {
        this.userMobNo = userMobNo;
    }

}
```

And my request handler in Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
String userData(UserFormBean bean){
    //code to handle incoming data
}
```

if user dosen't set any value in `'userEmail'` and `'userMobNo'` attributes at request time, spring by default sets `null` in these attributes and when i am getting value of these attributes in my request handler by `String str = bean.getUserEmail();` it returns me `null in double quote` like `"null"`.

Is there any way to convert these `null` values as `"" (blank)` when they contain `null` because i made an extra handler to handle these `"null"` values. Or some better idea to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to initialize the properties to the empty String:

```
private String userEmail = "";
private String userMobNo = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the setter is called with "\"null\"" for the new value.  Try this:

```
public void setUserEmail(final String newValue)
{
  if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(newValue) &&
      "\"null\"".equals(newValue))
  {
    userEmail = newValue;
  }
  else
  {
    userEmail = StringUtils.EMPTY;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a standard for naming your "web methods", for example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
String webUserData(UserFormBean bean){
    //code
}
```

When all your methods start with **web***, then you can write an aspect that will initalize all arguments as you would like.

If you need help about creating and defining an aspect, just ask.

**UPDATE: creating and defining an aspect**

I will not write the code for you, because it's much better for you to learn by reading the documentation - you will get to know a lot of extra details.

That said, the steps to create an aspect are:

1. [Enable AspectJ support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aspectj-support) - this step is done only once in your whole app
2. [Declare an aspect](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-at-aspectj) - create a class that has an @Aspect annotation
3. [Declare a pointcut](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts) inside your aspect - specify the point of interest in your code, around which the aspect will do some stuff, in your case, the **web*** methods
4. [Declare an advice](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-advice) inside your aspect - @Before, @AfterReturning, @AfterThrowing, @After, @Around, here you will write your specific aspect code

In your aspect code you will have to access the [current method arguments](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params) and do your logic for setting the empty string values for Strings.